# How di i convert a generator rated140v to 230v

Tags: electrical

How can I convert my generator rated 140v 35A to 230v, it came from Canada where they use 140v and this region  we use European standards of 230v,

Comment: I know of no part of the world that uses 140VAC for anything... Either you made a typo, or you have some piece of Chinese garbage made by people who have no idea what they are doing. there is more and more of that happening every day unfortunately. So for example:

Comment: We'd need to see an electrical diagram of the generator.

Comment: Forget my example referenced above, it was too late for editing. But if you can post the actual nameplate data it would be good.

Comment: Pending more info about the generator...  It might not be possible to convert it to 240v, in which case you would need a transformer.  High power transformers are so expensive, that you might just want to buy a new generator.  But again, more info is needed.

Comment: @JRaef  You can delete your first comment and start over.

Comment: With any luck, open the panel and move the setting switch or plug from 120 to 240 VAC output.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to adjust or modify the governor so the engine runs at 5/6 current speed (e.g. 1000/1500/3000 RPM instead of 1200/1800/3600). That is because 230V-land is also 50Hz.

You will need to tune generator excitation so that it works correctly at this speed.

Then you will need to rejumper, rewire or rewind the generator for 240V instead of 120V.  This might be quite easy. Or prohibitive. Depending on the generator.

Then you need to move the neutral-ground bonding so it is corner-grounded instead of center-grounded, except if you're using it at a construction site and not interlocking it with utility power, I wouldn't bother. Center-grounding is a virtue in that application; Britain even requires it.

Finally change the receptacles from North American to the ones you find convenient.

Plan B: sell it on Craigslist to some American who brought over US tools without thinking about voltage, and buy the right thing.

Comment: I detect a bit of sarcasm  here, but good call. Too much effort is spent in trying to make existing stuff work when replacement is a far superior solution.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Harper sarcastic????  Never!!  LOL  He just likes to throw up the strawman so he can shoot it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  For this old timer, trying to fix stuff is just in my blood. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I love fixing things and making them last too.   But in his case, it's a stretch. I've wasted too much time and money trying to "save money".  In the end it's "penny wise and pound foolish".